# How to check if deserealized class members have value?

Tags: c#, deserialization

I have an initial snippet which deserealized parameters, checks for value and handles the error:

```
var param = js.Deserialize<int?>(jqData.Params);


if (param.HasValue)
{
     resp.ReturnValue = param.Value;
}
else
{
     //handle error code
}
```

Now, during my modification, I have changed the method to accept a list of class parameters instead of nullable integers

```
var param = js.Deserialize<ClassName>(jqData.Params);
```

Now it invalidates .HasValue and .Value methods.

My question is: **How do I properly modify these two lines so it would hold the same meaning as initial if statement?**

Thus far I only thought about switching to `if (param != null)`, but I cannot think of proper equivalent to .Value.

Comment: If `ClassName` is a class - its value is in the `param`. Being a reference type means that `null` is one of possible values naturally.

Comment: @zerkms You mean, the whole if statement becomes unnecessary?

Comment: Well, `param` holds a reference to the object. If it is `!= null`, then it definitely refers to an object.

Comment: @zerkms Wait, then the whole if else statement is unnecessary?

Comment: You are deserializing to a nullable int in the first statement and to ClassName in the second. ClassName does not have properties (I'm guessing) called HasValue and Value as these are native to the nullable int.

Comment: It's not possible to say that, you have not explained what the expected outcome is.

Comment: @zerkms After doing some additional research, the whole if-else indeed becomes irrelevant. So thanks for tipping me in the right direction.

Comment: @zerkms You can get is as an answer, so I will accept it and close question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as `ClassName` is a class (see - a reference type) you just need to check if it is not `null`.

If it is not - then the variable holds a reference to an object that you use as-is.