# How to declare an array of deserialized class parameters without initializing it?

Tags: c#, arrays, deserialization

I consider this as a continuation of what I've learned from my two previous threads. Instead of Javascript I will be using pure C#.

I have a class with 3 parameters in it, and I am creating a variable which is a result of deserialization to class type

```
var param = js.Deserialize<ClassName>(jqData.Params);
```

Based on what I've learned from my [first thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39967822/how-to-check-if-deserealized-class-members-have-value), it stores values based on inputs I've made within 3 textboxes that I have.

For our purposes, let's assume I only placed input in a second textbox out of three, so the values would be `null, "abc", null`.

Now, I got some very good suggestions from my [second post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39981208/how-to-check-if-only-one-value-is-not-null-in-javascript), which I want to implement.

I want to create an array of objects, WITHOUT initializing, since those objects already hold values, reduce array down to 1 element based on criteria from [that excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391743/how-many-elements-of-array-are-not-null), and then proceed with my validation logic.

However, I am struggling with declaring array part. From what I saw here in SO, most of threads are talking about declaring and initializing those elements. I don't need it.

What I need is to declare an array, which would have class elements in it, something like `array = [param.elem1, param.elem2, param.elem3]`, and when I run a code, it will return `[null, "abc", null]`.

**Can you please point me in the right direction on how to properly declare such array?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea was close to how this can be handled. Just change your `array = [param.elem1, param.elem2, param.elem3]` to:

```
var myArray = new object[] { param.elem1, param.elem2, param.elem3 };
```

If you know the type of param.elem1/2/3, you can use the specific type (e.g. `string[]` instead of `object[]`).

Comment: I will test it out tomorrow morning and tell you the results.

Comment: Yep, looks like exactly what I need, thank you very much!